# Jest not mocking axios function when the axios request is located in a helper file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, axios

I have got Jest successfully mocking an axios request for my test function however it only works when axios itself is called from the component that is being tested. When I switch it out to use a helper file (`Request.js`) that i've created to normalise requests the axios request no longer gets mocked.

In the component that is being tested I have tried putting a simple axios request in like so:

```
axios.request({
    url: '/test'
}).then(data => {
    console.log("Mock data");
    console.log(data);
})
```

This request works fine and gets mocked by my `axios.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
            status: 200,
            payload: {}
        }
    )),
    request: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve("Hello World"))
};
```

When I log out the response to the request it returns "Hello World" which is the expected behaviour and shows it is being correctly mocked.

However, when I switch this out for my helper, the request no longer gets mocked.

```
Request.get(routes.client.info)
    .then(data => {
        console.log("DATA");
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

The .get method exists on the Request class and looks like so:

```
static get(url, {params = {}, headers = {}} = {}, returnFullResponse = false) {
    return this.request(url.get || url, {
        method: "GET",
        body: {},
        headers,
        params
    }, returnFullResponse);
}
```

This method executes the `request` method which executes the axios request:

```
static request(url, {method, body = {}, headers = {}, params = {}}, returnFullResponse) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.request({
                url,
                method,
                responseType: 'json',
                data: body,
                headers,
                params
            })
                .then(result => {
                    if(GLOB_VARS && GLOB_VARS.debugMode) {
                        super.logRequest(url, method, result.data);
                    }
                    result = returnFullResponse ? result : result.data;
                    resolve(result);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    if(err.response && err.response.status && err.response.statusText) {
                        super.logError(url, err.response.status, err.response.statusText);
                        const { status, statusText, data } = err.response;
                        reject({
                            status: status,
                            message: statusText,
                            data: data
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        reject({
                            status: null,
                            message: err
                        })
                    }
                })
        });
    }
```

I am unsure why it is not being mocked as in my component file I can successfully mock the `request` method on Axios however when I make the request using the helper I get `undefined` as the returned output from axios.

Any ideas?

Comment: I never heard of mocking by re-exporting. You are only overriding your own copy, not of what had already got a handle of axios before you re-exported it. You should mock just the functions, then the reference stays the same for everyone. I'm pretty sure your component that uses it is not receiving your mocked version directly

Comment: I suspected that the component is not getting the mocked version, thanks for clarifying that. However, I need to mock the request that's being fired in the component because the result from the axios request dictates state changes in the component.

Comment: I suggest you use https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-axios I don't use either axios or jest, but this package seems to do what most other frameworks let you do by intercepting the existing jest methods as I suggested in my first comment. You can also use [dependency injection](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/software-gardening/1284/dependency-injection-solid-principles) on your component so you can pass a mocked axios object